# Magento manually change order status to 'complete'

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to manually change order status to complete at a certain point in my code. This is what I have so far:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_GET['orderid']);
$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE, true, 'Pedido completado exitosamente.', true, false)->save();
```

When I do that I get the error:

```
The Order state 'complete' must not be set manually.
```

Ok so I tried this:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_GET['orderid']);
$order->setStatus("complete");
$order->save();
```

When I do that I get the error:

```
Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object
```

So how can I manually set the order status to complete.

I tried with the first one commenting out the following lines in `Sales/Order.php`:

```
if ($shouldProtectState) {
            if ($this->isStateProtected($state)) {
                Mage::throwException(
                    Mage::helper('sales')->__('The Order State "%s" must not be set manually.', $state)
                );
            }
        }
```

But no go, I still get the not setting to complete error above.

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First get the order ID like you already did:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_GET['orderid']);
```

and then,

Try

```
$order->addStatusToHistory(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
```

OR

```
$order->setData('state', Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
$order->save();
```

You can't set Order state to COMPLETE or CLOSED manually with `setState()` method AFAIK.

Comment: Sorry, this throws the following error `Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object`

Comment: that may be because of some other error.. `getMethodInstance()` generally occurs for Payment Method. Your error says that you are trying to get the Payment Method on a non-object

Comment: I'm trying to set status of order on the success page after full payment. For some reason Magento no longer is setting payment status when it comes back. So in my payment module I'm trying to set payment on final success page. It's on the `onestepcheckout` success page that I'm trying to set it. The error only happens when I add that stuff to the page, if I don't add that stuff no error.

Comment: The problem is in setting payment method code. Or in the worst case, you are loading the order which does not exist or is invalid, so it's not getting the payment method details.

Answer (score 5):

I use

```
$order->addStatusHistoryComment("My comment why the status was changed", 
Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE);
```

The method addStatusToHistory is deprecated according to the Mage_Sales_Model_Order code.